# Changing Symfony\Component\Process code in laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, symfony-process

I have found a problem in the symfony package and I have a very little fix I want to implement. How to change it with my own code and implement it globally in my laravel.

Comment: Why not report this as a bug and get it fixed in the original repository? If you already have a fix at hand, simply submit a pull request

Comment: That's because I'm not sure. The problem lies when I use another package and I trace it to the symfony/process. I need a quick fix first so, yes until I'm sure it's a bug, I will do a quick fix first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fork the package make the changes, and have the composer package point to your version instead of the primary location.

Here is a quick recap of how to do it:

```php
// for the require
// assuming you forked the repo and made the changes on master branch
require: {
   "symfony/process": "dev-master"
}

// if you don't have this key simply add it:
// replace: YOURNAME with your name (this assumes you are using github, any git repo URL will work)
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/YOURNAME/process"
    }
]
```

Then simply run: `composer update`

Here is a longer guide and explanation:

https://medium.com/swlh/using-your-own-forks-with-composer-699358db05d9

Might be worth doing a pull request to the maintainer of the package as well, this way you can simply remove your forked package and simply update when the maintainer updates their version.

Comment: have you ever tried it on laravel? I try it, but with no success because there is a lot of dependencies locked to that version

Comment: @FendyHarianto yep, as long as the project uses composer the framework is irrelevant.  However if composer asks you for a specific version, simply check the version you are currently using in composer.json or composer.lock and use the `as`


`require: {
   "symfony/process": "dev-master as 5.3.0"
}`

Comment: Ah I see, I forget that step, thanks